# Swift: Algorithm To Change A Random Number After Multiple Loops

Tags: swift, for-loop, random, sprite-kit, direction

I want to let the zombies move 30 times in one random direction and after that change the direction of every zombie individually. I have multiple zombies. All of them should NOT move in the same direction. I am sure I am missing something stupid. My code:

```
for zombie in Zombies{
    if(zombieCounter >= 30){
        for zombie in Zombies{
            direction = Int(arc4random_uniform(4))
            switch direction{
            case 0:
                zombie.position.y += step
                zombie.direction = 1
            case 1:
                zombie.position.y -= step
                zombie.direction = 2
            case 2:
                zombie.position.x -= step
                zombie.direction = 3
            case 3:
                zombie.position.x += step
                zombie.direction = 4
            default:()
            }
        }
        zombieCounter = 0
    }
}

zombieCounter += 1
```

Before I had this code:

```
if(zombieCounter >= 25){
    zombieCounter = 0
    for zombie in Zombies{
        let direction = arc4random_uniform(4)
        switch direction{
        case 0: zombie.position.y += stepZombie
        zombie.direction = 0
        case 1: zombie.position.y -= stepZombie
        zombie.direction = 1
        case 2: zombie.position.x -= stepZombie
        zombie.direction = 2
        case 3: zombie.position.x += stepZombie
        zombie.direction = 3
        default:()
        }
    }
}
```

It gets a random direction for each of the zombies and moves the zombie just once. What I want to do is to move the zombies multiple time in the same direction without a for-loop in the cases. The function should be called one time. The next time the direction should be the same like the first time. After 30 runs the direction should be randomly calculated for each of the zombies.

```
    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
        if !gameOver{
            let step: CGFloat = 5
            let stepZombie: CGFloat = 20
            var zombieMovement = 20

            if(zombieCounter >= 25){
                zombieCounter = 0
                for zombie in Zombies{
                    let direction = arc4random_uniform(4)
                    switch direction{
                    case 0: zombie.position.y += stepZombie
                    zombie.direction = 0
                    case 1: zombie.position.y -= stepZombie
                    zombie.direction = 1
                    case 2: zombie.position.x -= stepZombie
                    zombie.direction = 2
                    case 3: zombie.position.x += stepZombie
                    zombie.direction = 3
                    default:()
                    }
                }
            }
            zombieCounter += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you looping through `Zombies` twice?

Comment: @Arc676 If not every zombie would have the same direction which I don't want.

Comment: Not if you generate a random `direction` in every iteration.

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint at this line `direction = Int(arc4random_uniform(4))`: and see if the number in direction is same all the time.

Comment: It isn't. I should have included more details how the rest in it works. Let me think some more to fix my problem. Is is hard to describe.

Comment: @Arc676 I updated the question

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: It could be the lines like `zombie.position.y += step`. What is step? It might be your issue.

Comment: @CalebKleveter Step is not the issue. So I am using SpiteKit and step is basically the step the zombie should take on the screen. So it moves the zombie on the screen by 5px. And I dont want to repeat this movement 30 times into the same direction.

Comment: You have zombieCounter >= 25 it should be <= 25

Comment: No this is correct. Every time the function is called (60 times a second) it should move the zombie then. Moving it 60 times a second make the zombie really fast. To slow it down the movement get triggered every 25th run.  I could also use ==

Comment: I want to see the whole function. Because what I see now is the For loop is run and the if statement is checked, the counter is more then 30 (I assume you probably start it at 30 so the direction is randomly selected) so the direction is randomly created the zombie moves then the loops end and the counter is incremented, then the code is over. Thus the zombies move just once.

Comment: @CalebKleveter I added the whole function. Not this function is called by SpriteKit before each frame is rendered (60 times a second).

Comment: The function *is* called every time the screen is rendered? Here is what I see: This line `zombie.position.y += stepZombie` (or the one's like it) are only called `if(zombieCounter >= 25)` So you add 1 to zombie counter after the if statement is run, but the zombie only moves if the counter is equal to or more then 25. Am I missing something?

Comment: @CalebKleveter No this is correct. Every time the function is called (60 times a second) it should move the zombie then. Moving it 60 times a second make the zombie really fast. To slow it down the movement get triggered every 25th run.

Comment: Are we going to move to chat?

Comment: @CalebKleveter If you could send me a hyperlink to the chat. I am currently on my phone. But do you understand what I am trying to get?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95588/discussion-between-caleb-kleveter-and-lukas-kohl).

Comment: In the link should be in the previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lukas Köhl,  we already established an enemy class for you in our chat from your last question you posted,  so what we want to do is take advantage of that.

Keep a counter for the amount of steps that you want each zombie to take,  and set it as a property.

```
override var moveCounter : Int  = 30
{
    didSet{
       if(moveCounter == 0)
       {
         direction = Int(arc4random_uniform(4)) + 1
         moveCounter = 30
       }
    }
}
```

Then, after every step the zombie takes,  we do `zombie.moveCounter--`
    (Eventually I would like to help you get all of this into the class)

Comment: Well.Did not expected this.

Comment: Lukas, It appears that someone has changed the circumstances of your problem. Nonetheless, did your question get answered?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
class Zombie {
    var position = CGPoint()
    var direction: UInt32 = 0
}

let maxSteps = 25
var Zombies = [Zombie]()
var gameOver = false
var stepsInCurrentDirection = MaxSteps

func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    if !gameOver {
        //let step: CGFloat = 5
        //var zombieMovement = 20

        let stepZombie: CGFloat = 20
        let changeDirection = stepsInCurrentDirection >= maxSteps

        for zombie in Zombies {
            if changeDirection { zombie.direction = arc4random_uniform(4) }
            switch zombie.direction {
                case 0: zombie.position.y += stepZombie
                case 1: zombie.position.y -= stepZombie
                case 2: zombie.position.x -= stepZombie
                case 3: zombie.position.x += stepZombie
                default:()
            }
        }

        if changeDirection { stepsInCurrentDirection = 1 }
        else { stepsInCurrentDirection += 1 }
    }
}
```